# My laptop has 2 graphics card (AMD)

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, amd-radeon, gaming, specifications

I have recently discovered that my Toshiba SATELLITE L50D-B, has 2 graphics card built in: AMD Radeon R5 M230 Series(1024MB) and AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics(4GB).

I am wondering why I have 2 of them and I want to know which one is being used when I am playing games? Which is the real or main card of the system?

**MY LAPTOP SPECS**

- Processor - AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics, Manufacturer AMD, Speed  2.0 GHz, Number of Cores    4
- Video Card 1 - AMD Radeon R5 M230 Series, Manufacturer    ATI, Chipset    Radeon R5 M230, Dedicated Memory    1024 MB, Total Memory   1024 MB
- Video Card 2 - AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics, Manufacturer   ATI, Chipset    AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics, Dedicated Memory    3.0 GB, Total Memory    4.0 GB
- Memory - 8.0 GB
- Operating System - Microsoft Windows 10 (build 10240), 64-bit, Service Pack   0, Size 64 Bit Edition
- Display Maximum Resolution - 1366 x 768
- DVD - MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8G2
- CD - MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8G2
- Drive:    Size    918.6 GB, Free  503.6 GB

Comment: They are the same card, one is a virtual adapter. Probably the second one.

Comment: Google "Switchable Graphics"

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop uses the A8-6410 APU.  "APU" is AMD's name for the combination of a multi-core CPU and an iGPU on the same die, with tightly coupled access to system memory.  Yours is a low-end model using Puma CPU cores, which are designed for low power consumption and ease of manufacture rather than particularly high performance.

The "Radeon™ R5 Graphics" refers to the iGPU built into your APU.

The "Radeon R5 M230 Series" refers to an additional dGPU; it is a low-end model normally used to provide Dual Graphics support.  "Dual Graphics" is AMD's term for a form of Crossfire (multi-GPU) operation between an iGPU and a small dGPU.  The display is physically attached to the iGPU, so frames rendered by the dGPU are transmitted to the iGPU for display.

Generally the dGPU has roughly the same performance as the iGPU by itself, but the intention is for games to use both GPUs to obtain nearly doubled performance.  In practice, Dual Graphics doesn't work very well on modern game engines, which tend to be rather unfriendly to Crossfire configurations.  In that case, performance will be similar to using the iGPU alone.